# Reversed sublists on even numbers

Tags: haskell, erlang, ocaml, reverse, sublist

I have a list L

```
L = [ [0, 3, 1], [7, 2], [5, 11], [7],[] ]
```

And I need the output to return that list of lists, but for every even sublist it should reverse it, so that the output will be:

```
L = [ [1, 3, 0], [7, 2], [11, 5], [7],[] ]
```

Assuming we count position from 0.

I probably need to get information about how many sublists does the list contain, and then reverse every even sublist.

Comment: Yes, 2D. List containing other lists.

Comment: 2D array or 2D linked list?

Comment: Same as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286668/reverse-even-sublists-of-a-list

Answer (score 3):

Here's a skeleton for a solution in Haskell, by straight-forward pattern matching:

```
reverseEverySecond :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
reverseEverySecond []           = []
reverseEverySecond [x]          = [reverse x]
reverseEverySecond (x : y : ys) = ... -- use reverse appropriately and recurse on ys
```

Answer (score 1):

For reversing a single list, you can just use the built in `reverse` function.  For doing it on alternating elements, there are several ways you could go about it.  You could write a function like this

```
addEveryOther :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
addEveryOther n (x:y:xs) = x + n : y : addEveryOther xs
addEveryOther n (x:[]) = x + n : []
addEveryOther n [] = []
```

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
addEveryOther n xs = map go $ zip [0..] xs
    where
        go (i, x) = if even i then x + n else x
```

But that would probably be slower since it involves more operations and creating and then immediately destructing tuples.

Comment: @nobodynoone I'm sure this is by design. You haven't provided any attempt or code yourself, so you shouldn't expect a complete answer, just a few hints.

Comment: @nobodynoone Stackoverflow is not a place to request answers, it's a place to request help.  Read the FAQ, follow the rules.  I've given you the information you need to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @nobodynoone Here on Stackoverflow, answers are given with the assumption that the asker actually wants to solve their problem, not just be spoon fed the answer.  If all you're wanting is someone to write what looks like a homework problem for you, go to another forum.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a combination of

```
cycle [id, reverse] :: [[a] -> [a]]

zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]

map (uncurry ($)) :: [(a -> b, a)] -> [b]
```