# Can someone explain how this OCaml function which reverses the elements of a list works?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have an OCaml function which I got from the post: [List reversing in Ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286668/list-reversing-in-ocaml?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
let rev_list l =
      let rec rev_acc acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | hd::tl -> rev_acc (hd::acc) tl
      in 
      rev_acc [] l
```

I tested this, and it obviously worked, but I don't understand why. Inside the main function, when defining `rev_acc`, it says that it only takes on argument `acc`. However, when then call the function with two parameters. Why are we allowed to do this?

Also, why do we say `let rec rev_acc acc = function`, what does the "= function" mean, and why aren't we using a match? I'm assuming this has to do with not having to specify certain arguments; I do remember something about that in the last part of the course, which was only briefly covered. Does it have anything to do with currying?

Sorry if these are stupid questions; I'm rather new to functional programming, if that wasn't already obvious.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ocaml has a special `function` syntax which takes an implicit argument and automatically inserts it into the match expressions to follow

The `rev_acc` function in your program is defined using `function`

```
let rec rev_acc acc = function
  | [] -> acc
  | hd::tl -> rev_acc (hd::acc) tl
```

This is equivalent to

```
let rec rev_acc acc xs =
  match xs with
    | [] -> acc
    | hd::tl -> rev_acc (hd::acc) tl
```

Above, each version of `rev_acc` accepts **two** arguments

Comment: F#, which is derived from Ocaml, has the same keyword that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that rev_acc is a function that takes one argument. BUT it then returns a function taking another argument. So when you write

```
rev_acc [] l
```

what actually happens is

```
let unnamed_function = rev_acc []
in
unnamed_function l
```